# How to set environment variable in Postman depending on other values in response?

Tags: environment-variables, postman

Using GET request, I have the following response:

```
 [
        {
            "id": "ID_1",
            "name": "",
            "color": "orange"
        },
        {
            "id": "ID_2",
            "name": "",
            "color": "yellow"
        },
        {
            "id": "ID_3",
            "name": "",
            "color": "red"
        },
    ....
    ]
```

I need to set each ID as a environment variable. At first I did it using:

```
pm.environment.set("Orange_ID", jsonData[0].id);
pm.environment.set("Yellow_ID", jsonData[1].id);
pm.environment.set("Red_ID", jsonData[2].id);
```

And it works. But then I noticed that whenever I send a request, the order in the response is not the same. For example, the first is yellow, the second red, and so on.
So I need to change variables.

Could you please help me how I can

```
set "Orange_ID" variable where color = orange
set "Yellow_ID" variable where color = yellow
set "Red_ID" variable where color = red
```

Thank you!

Comment: Similar question https://stackoverflow.com/a/72022210/7574461